# looping is not done

Tags: php, jpeg

Here i have written a small code...in this looping is not done..only first image is displaying..Actually there are 7 images...Please help me on this

```
 <?php

$username = "root";
$password = "root";
$host = "localhost";
$database = "test";
error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_PARSE);
mysql_connect($host, $username, $password) or die("Can not connect to database: ".mysql_error());

mysql_select_db($database) or die("Can not select the database: ".mysql_error());


header('Content-type: image/jpg');

$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tbl_images");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query))
{
echo $content = $row['image']."</br>";
echo $content;
}
?>
```

Comment: can you tell us that what do you want in result?

Comment: tried replacing `echo $content = $row['image']."</br>";` with ` $content = $row['image']."</br>";`?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can't merge 7 (or any number) of jpeg images into one just by concatenating them together. And `<br/>` certainly has no place within jpeg.

Comment: Hi a blob image is there in my table......I have this  <header('Content-type: image/jpg');> in my code. please check ...able to see only one(first image) ....

Comment: @k102...iam very newbie to php...{<?php
   header("Content-type: image/jpg");
  $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM products") or die (mysql_error());
  
 
  while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql))
{
 echo '<img src="'.$row['picture'].'">';
}

 ?>}  here picture is path..i able to see only one image ..how should i see all images..pls help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_PARSE);

$username = "root";
$password = "root";
$host = "localhost";
$database = "test";

mysql_connect($host, $username, $password) or die("Can not connect to database: ".mysql_error());

mysql_select_db($database) or die("Can not select the database: ".mysql_error());

//header('Content-type: image/jpg');

$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tbl_images");

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
    echo '<img src="'.$row['image'].'" width=40 height=40>';// remove width and height later
}
?>
```

Comment: Hi a blob image is there in my table......I have this  <header('Content-type: image/jpg');> in my code. please check ...able to see only one(first image) ....

Comment: @CoolBoy what if u remove `header('Content-type: image/jpg');`

Comment: got error...<Fatal error: Call to undefined function mysql_fetecharray() in C:\wamp\www\items\shh.php>

Comment: @CoolBoy add _ `mysql_fetech_array()`

Comment: @k102...iam very newbie to php...{<?php
   header("Content-type: image/jpg");
  $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM products") or die (mysql_error());
  
 
  while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql))
{
 echo '<img src="'.$row['picture'].'">';
}

 ?>}  here picture is path..i able to see only one image ..how should i see all images..pls help me

Comment: @CoolBoy see if all images existe or do this `echo '<img src="'.$row['picture'].'" width=40 height=40>`

Comment: @mgraph...thanku..yes images are there..A box is coming..but those are not displaying.....{$sql = "SELECT serial, name, description, price,picture FROM products;";
  $result = mysql_query($sql) or die (mysql_error());
  while(list($id, $name, $description, $price,$picture) = mysql_fetch_row($result)) 
  { 
  echo "<tr>";
   echo "<td align=left>";
   echo '<img src="'.$picture.'" width=40 height=40>';
   echo "</td>"; 
   echo "</tr>";
  }}

Comment: <?php
echo '<img src="'."C:\wamp\www\shopping\images\cdrom-drive.jpg".'" width=40 height=40>';
?>.....this image is not displaying..getting a box type(and 'x' mark also not getting which tells no image is there)...why it is not diplsying pls help me...thank u

Comment: @CoolBoy this way `echo '<img src="http://localhost/shopping/images/cdrom-drive.jpg" width=40 height=40>'; ?>` path should not be relative to you computer it should be realtive to server

Comment: Many thanks million times.....now displyed...thank u very much mgraph..thanks for pointing out..am always giving my system path that is wrong...Thanks again

Answer (score 2):

what is actualy in your database? if there's a path to image, you should output it like

`echo '<img src="'.$row['image'].'">';`

and if there's a blob data with an image - you can only output one of them using `header('Content-type: image/jpg');`. so you can create a page which will print desired image.

Comment: Hi a blob image is there in my table......I have this  <header('Content-type: image/jpg');> in my code. please check ...able to see only one(first image) ....

Comment: @Cool Boy: you can only display one image at a time, just like k102 told you.

Comment: Mchl...thanks for ur reply...here is my another code...which i have path in my db....{<?php
  header("Content-type: image/jpg");
  $sql = "SELECT serial, name, description, price,picture FROM products;";
  
  $result = mysql_query($sql) or die (mysql_error());
  
  while(list($id, $name, $description, $price,$picture) = mysql_fetch_row($result)) { 
   
   echo "<tr>";
   
   echo "<td align=left>";
   echo '<img src="'.$picture.'">';
   echo "<a href=\"cart.php?action=add&id=$id\">Add To Cart</a>";
   echo "<hr size=\"1\" >";   
   echo "</td>"; 
   echo "</tr>";
   
  }
  
 ?>}

Comment: @CoolBoy, you realy have to learn html and another basics before starting to learn **any** programming language. cause it's hard to decide from which point to start an explanation to you

Comment: @k102...iam very newbie to php...{<?php
   header("Content-type: image/jpg");
  $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM products") or die (mysql_error());
  
 
  while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql))
{
 echo '<img src="'.$row['picture'].'">';
}

 ?>}  here picture is path..i able to see only one image ..how should i see all images..pls help me